# How to build for loops in VHDL with higher increment rates?

Tags: for-loop, vhdl

I would like to transform a C `for loop` into a **for..generate** statement in VHDL.

Here is the monster:

```
for (j = J; j+d < (2 << g); j += 2*d)
```

My steps so far:

1. rename `j` to `k` to avoid trouble with `J`
   `for (k = J; k+d < (2 << g); k += 2*d)`
2. `2 << g` is replaced by `1 << (g+1)`
   `for (k = J; k+d < (1 << (g+1)); k += 2*d)`
3. `1 << (g+1)` is replaced by `2**(g+1)`
   `for (k = J; k+d < (2**(g+1)); k += 2*d)`
4. make upper bound inclusive: `j+d <= (2**g)-1`
   `for (k = J; k+d <= (2**(g+1))-1; k += 2*d)`
5. iterationen stops at `j <= (2**(g+1))-d-1`
   `for (k = J; k <= (2**(g+1))-d-1; k += 2*d)`

VHDL Code so far:

```
-- outer loops
genK : for k in J to (2**(g+1))-d-1 generate
begin
  -- more generate loops ...
end generate;
```

**How can I transform `k += 2*d`?**

The complete *odd-even mergesort* algorithm can be found at that [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426337/how-to-fix-this-non-recursive-odd-even-merge-sort-algorithm).

**My next steps:**

6. move the loop range to be zero-based
   `for (k = 0; k <= (2**(g+1))-J-d-1; k += 2*d)`
7. increment by is `2*d`, but the generate loop has `1`. So it must be normalized to `1`, by dividing. `k` must be renamed to `kk`:
   `for (kk = 0; kk <= ((2**(g+1))-J-d-1) / (2*d); kk++)`
8. now `k` can be restored in the loop:
   `k = kk * 2*d + J`

VHDL Code so far:

```
-- outer loops
genK : for kk in 0 to ((2**(g+1))-J-d-1) / (2*d) generate
  constant k  : NATURAL := (kk * 2 * d) + J;
begin
  -- more generate loops ...
end generate;
```

Comment: Prior to converting the loop from C to VHDL, would you mind explaining why are you doing this? Are you implementing a sorting algorithm using VHDL?

Comment: I have already implemented various sorting networks in VHDL: odd-even sort, bitonic sort, ... odd-even mergesort  requires less comperators than bitonic sort and thus gives more space on an FPGA. The linked SO question has links to the other implementations. We are implementing an FPGA framework and my sorting network is an example of an data intensive workload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like:

```
genK : for k in J to (2**(g+1))-d-1 generate
begin
  gen2d : if ((k - J) mod (2 * d)) = 0 generate
    -- stuff
  end generate gen2d;
end generate;
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a function generate the list of values you need.  Inside the function you can use `while loop`, populate the list and use the `exit` statement to break the loop.  This way you can have more control over you loop implementation.

```
type integer_vector is array (natural range <>) of integer;

function generate_indexes(J : integer; <some parms> ) return integer_vector is
    variable result : integer_vector( some range );
    variable index  : integer;
    variable j      : integer;
    variable d      : integer;
    variable g      : integer;
begin
    while true loop

        -- calculate the value for j, d and g

        result(index) := j;

        if <break condition> then
            exit;
        end if;
        j := j + 2*d;

    end loop;

    return result;
end function;
```

Then use it like this

```
genK : for j in generate_indexes(<some parms>) generate
    -- code
end generate;
```

I guess this tends to be easier to understand and test the code.

Comment: Nice idea, but I think you can't use a integer_vector where a range is expexted. The vector should be stored in a constant and each element should be accessed by the loop index.

Answer (score -1):

Not using a for/generate statement, but I think this should cover most of the algorithm.

```
while bBreak = false loop
  temp1 := j + d;           -- store j + d into variable
  temp2 := (others => '0'); -- initial set compare value to 0
  temp2(g+1) := '1';        -- set the MSB (2 << g)
  if temp1 < temp2 then     -- compare
     bBreak <= true;        -- set break variable
  else
     j <= j + 2*d;          -- set j to the new value (j += 2*d)
  end
end loop
```

I think you could optmize the comparison, when you get the MSB of the resulting vector, but not sure about it.

Comment: A generate statement is required to instantiate entities at the generated index values. Your solution misses several points: a) no signal or variable declarations, because temp2 seams to be no INTEGER; b) Why is `bBreak` a signal and no variable like `temp1/2`?

Comment: You are right. I skipped the types of the signals/variables. I assumed all signals/variables to be std_ulogic_vector, where temp1 and temp2 are variables and bBreak is a signal. since you target an FPGA, I assume that this will run in a clocked process => bBreak can be a signal.

Comment: That's my problem I can't run it in (clocked) process. The elements in the sorting network might be exchangable.

Comment: Did I understand the algorithm correct, that you know a-priori the number of elements you want to sort (i.e. at compile time)? And the generate loop is used to instantiate swapping elements (like: if in_a < in_b then out_a <= in_a; out_b <= in_b; else out_a <= in_b; out_b <= in_a; end)?

Comment: Yes, the size is known. That's why I can construct a sorting network. It can be used as a pre-sorter. If used with a CPU, the CPU can divide the data set into chunks of the sortnet size. After each chunk is sorted a fast merge sort can be performed on the pre-sorted results.